# Question about initialization. The output must be zeros with C++11 and afterwards?

Tags: c++, c++11

Question about initialization. The output must be zeros with C++11 and afterwards for the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/hxGjdxrGf) below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Point{int x;int y;};

struct Line {Point start; Point end;};

class Demo{
public:
    Demo() = default;
    Line line;
};

int main()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<Demo>();
    std::cout << ptr->line.start.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << ptr->line.start.y << std::endl;

    Demo demo;
    std::cout << demo.line.start.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << demo.line.start.y << std::endl;

    Demo demo1{};
    std::cout << demo1.line.start.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << demo1.line.start.y << std::endl;
}
```

I am rellay confused now. Could someone shed some light on this matter?

Comment: The `{}` on the last declaration will zero the object. The middle decl should not be initializated since no initialization is asked for. Not sure about the first.

Comment: Found it. The non-initialization of `Line line` makes it undefined when reading it

Comment: `Demo demo1{};` is zeroed, `Demo demo;` isn't. `make_shared` uses `()`, so it's also zeroed. All this zeroing only applies if the default constructor is implicitly generated or explicitly `=default`ed in the class body, as you did.

Comment: change `struct Point` into `struct Point{ int x{0}; int y{0}; }` if you always want initialized values for x and y (can be expensive for large collections of points). Or change Demo to have its Line member always initialized e.g. `Line line{};`. The bottom line is C++ will NEVER initialize variables unless you explicitly ask it to do so

Comment: This question could use more text. How is the next person with the same question supposed to find this? Search for the word "confused"?

Answer (score 7):

> I am rellay confused now. Could someone shed some light on this matter?

Let us consider each case separately.

##### Case 1

Here we consider `auto ptr = std::make_shared<Demo>();`.

In this case you're using `make_shared` with `()` aka **value initialization** which will value-initialize the object. This means the data member `line` will be value initialized here which will in turn value intialize its data members `start` and `end`. Finally, value initialization of `start` and `end` will zero its own data members `x` and `y`.

##### Case 2

Here we consider `Demo demo;`

`Demo demo` is **default initialization** and `demo` will be created using the defaulted **default constructor** which will use defalt constructor of `line`. Next, `Line`'s default constructor will use default constructor of `Point`. Finally, `Point`'s default constructor will be used which will leave the built in data member `x` and `y` uninitialized.

##### Case 3

Here we consider `Demo demo1{};`

This is **zero initialization(aka list initialization)** and will also as the name suggests, zero initialize the data members. This means the data member `line` will be zero initialized which in turn implies that `start` and `end` will also be zero initialized. This also means that the data members `x` and `y` will also be zero initialized.